# Send Email only if the field value changes

Tags: apex, trigger, apex-email-service, massemailmessage

I have a below trigger created where I use a field called Hiring Manger to identify the user's email id and send an email to the person that a project is assigned to them. But my trigger runs every time a do some edit to the record with out changing the hiring manger field. I would like to send an email only if the previous value does not match the current value in hiring manager field. How can i implement this condition here:

```
trigger SendEmailToHiringManger on SFDC_Job_Opening__c (after insert, after update) {

    list<SFDC_Job_Opening__c> i = [select id,SO__c,SFDC_Job_Opening__c.Hiring_Manager__r.email,Account_Name__c from SFDC_Job_Opening__c where id IN:trigger.newMap.keySet()];

    for( SFDC_Job_Opening__c s : i)
    {

        system.debug('Name is'+ s.Hiring_Manager__c);
        String userEmail = s.Hiring_Manager__r.email; 
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {userEmail}; 
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
        mail.setSubject('You have a project assigned' + ' So#- '+ s.SO__c); 
        String body = 'Project Assigned' + '-' + s.SO__c + ' ' + s.Account_Name__c ; 
        mail.setPlainTextBody(body); 
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEMailMessage[]{mail});

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the 'old' and the 'new values in an after trigger. You already access the new values in `trigger.newMap`. The old values are in `trigger.oldMap` :-)

So compare the old and new value of the field in your code.

```
trigger SendEmailToHiringManger on SFDC_Job_Opening__c (after insert, after update) {

list<SFDC_Job_Opening__c> i = [select id,SO__c,Hiring_Manager__r.email,Account_Name__c from SFDC_Job_Opening__c where id IN:trigger.newMap.keySet()];

for( SFDC_Job_Opening__c s : i)
{
    if(s.Hiring_Manager__c != trigger.oldMap.get(s.Id).Hiring_Manager__c)
    {
        system.debug('Name is'+ s.Hiring_Manager__c);
        String userEmail = s.Hiring_Manager__r.email; 
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {userEmail}; 
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses); 
        mail.setSubject('You have a project assigned' + ' So#- '+ s.SO__c); 
        String body = 'Project Assigned' + '-' + s.SO__c + ' ' + s.Account_Name__c ; 
        mail.setPlainTextBody(body); 
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEMailMessage[]{mail});
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

compare the value in the trigger.new vs the trigger.old to see if the hiring manager field has been updated.  If it has been updated then send the email..

Answer (score 0):

Create a workflow with second criteria and use ISCHANGED() , PRIORVALUE() != newValue

Create an email alert and send it using workflow